# Special Google Search Result - How to achieve this? (look at the attached image)

Tags: html, xhtml, dhtml

look at the following image

[image]

when searched for some websites... various websites show the above kind of result on google..

like serach for [stackoverflow](http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), [flickr](http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&q=flickr&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), [deviantart](http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&q=deviantart&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), [Hotmail](http://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=hotmail&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and so on

HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS...

Comment: Not programming related question... Check http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fernando : then i suppose we don't program\code websites.. you brain surgeon

Comment: this thing comes from with in the page.. google does not collect it from Fernandos HDD..

Comment: Google say they'll do it if they want to, if they think the site is that popular that it's worth; so there's nothing you can do to achieve it (except to make your site as big/popular as imdb, hotmail, etc.). Therefore this isn't programming-related.

Comment: Is this question related to programming or coding a website? No, it's related to SEO and getting a link on Google... And what's with the attitude?

Comment: Google doesnot do it.... its from within the page

Comment: Seriously @Moon if everyone is telling you it's done by Google and providing links there's probably a little more than a hint of truth in it.  If you don't want to believe it then you got absolutely no value from asking the question.

Comment: @Moon: The *links* come from the page that Google indexed, but the option to *show* those links are at Google's discretion. All of the content is from the site creator, true, but its *inclusion* in the search result is based on decisions that Google's algorithm makes, *not* at the request of the site creator.

Comment: Moon, it might come from Fernando's HDD if he owns the server where the site is.

Comment: I don't think Moon's question was "so" bad, after all, he did think it was programming related.

Comment: i didn't know about it thats why i asked it.. but guys here like Fernando just keep commenting instead of providing some useful info like in the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [google help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en):

"We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

At the moment, sitelinks are completely automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future."

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google builds those automatically, based on users' choices from their search pages.

This would explain how "Inception" and "Predator" show up there, when no one at imdb (probably) would specifically ask for a link for them.

Comment: No there really is a way to get Google to display sub-pages in this fashion... I'm not knowledgable about it, but it exists.

Comment: yes... it comes from within the page that the google result link is linking to... everything in google results is from the page...

Comment: When you search for Stack Overflow, one of the sitelinks is "OMG Ponies". Seriously.

Comment: I'm afraid other than requesting a link be removed you can only change your internal linking in a hope to update the sitelinks that appear.  Google "how to modify google sitelinks" for lots more info

Answer (score 0):

@James is correct, article taken from [Google's](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) site.  Also google for "google sitelink" to see more information